# Car won’t start after starter change

Tags: honda, civic, starter

My 2007 Honda Civic coupe had been starting weak for over a week, and it finally stopped starting two days ago. I ruled out the battery because my wipers, and headlights work, aswell as everything else that uses the battery. My battery’s also only a year and a half old. When I’d try to start the car before I’d hear I click, but now that I replaced the starter Hear the starter wering. It just sounds like it’s spinning, and nothing happens. I just hear the spinning, and the engine doesn’t make a sound. I don’t know what else it could be all the connections are made.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Michael Norris please edit the question.  Your second to the last sentence gives key symptoms of the problem and needs to be clear to help with diagnosis.

Comment: Thanks N8sBug I edited it, but I’m not sure what exactly you’d need to know. The only sound my car would make when I’d turn the key was that spinning sound.

Comment: Just because low-current items like lights and wipers work does not mean the battery is good. Just because a battery is only 18 months old does not mean the battery is good.

Answer (score 2):

Could be a faulty starter, the pinion is not engaging the flywheel ring-gear...

that could be:
 a solenoid problem (not moving the pinion) or

the pinion is stuck on the shaft or

it is the wrong starter (pinion does not move far enough to engage the flywheel)...

Seen all of these faults in the past so you will need to check.

Comment: Thank you for responding! I bought my starter to the store when I got the replacement to confirm it was in fact the correct one I was getting. How would I be able to check for the other issues you pointed out like the solenoid?

Comment: Test starter on the bench with a battery. Take measurements and work out if the teeth engage - if you are sure it is identical then it’s probably the solenoid...